# How to put icon next to link in rails app helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay so here's a problem i've got 2 methods in my application_helper.rb

```
def sidebar_link_to(body, url, icon)
html_options = {class: "sidebar-menu-item"}
link_to url, html_options do
  content_tag(:div, icon)
  content_tag(:span, body)
end
end
```

and

```
 def icon(filename, html_attributes = {})
begin
  path = "public/icons/#{filename}.svg"
  icon = Rails.root.join(path).read

  html = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse icon
  svg = html.at_css "svg"

  html_attributes.each { |name, value| svg[name] = value }
rescue Errno::ENOENT
  html = "<!-- SVG #{path} not found -->"
end
raw html
end
```

and here's my html.erb code

```
<%= sidebar_link_to "Maps", maps_path, icon("outline/map", class: "h-8 w-8 text-white") %>
```

I would like for my icon to show next to Maps link but somehow it doesn't work any ideas?

to clarify i would like the outcome from helper to be this but i can't find solution:

```
<div class="sidebar-menu-item group flex items-center">
   <%= icon "outline/map", class: "h-8 w-8 text-white"%>
   <%= link_to "Maps", maps_path %>
</div>
```

Comment: does icon method render anything if you use it alone, like in the last example?

Comment: Yes it renders svg, it’s adjustment to tailwindcss heroicons

Comment: I mean it renders icon and text next to it

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this](https://johno.com/gems/2013/12/02/link-with-icon-gem/), It is something related to your problem.